# Redis::InheritedError when calling Sidekiq worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, redis, sidekiq

Whenever I call a Sidekiq worker I'm getting the following error:

```
Redis::InheritedError (Tried to use a connection from a child process without reconnecting. You need to reconnect to Redis after forking.)
```

I'm hosting on Heroku and using Redis Cloud which I'm connecting to with connection_pool gem.

Here's the redis.rb:

```
if Rails.configuration.redis_uri.present?
  $redis = ConnectionPool.new(:size => 8, :timeout => 30) do
    Redis.new(:url => Rails.configuration.redis_uri)
  end
end
```

but don't think sidekiq is even using this as it's getting the Redis url directly from the REDIS_URL environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a forking webserver by any chance?

In this case, you might have to add this snippet from the readme: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Connecting-to-Redis#forking-app-server

Answer (score 1):

Don't touch the pool until after your web server has forked, i.e. Don't touch Redis during your app's initialization.